# problemas com sessão php expirando

Tags: php

Bom já sei que já fiz vários post aqui sobre sessão, porém esse erro e diferente.

Tenho um sistema de login onde a sessão tem que durar 2 horas, ou seja ela só pode expirar se o usuário não interagir com o sistema.

Minhas configurações estão assim:

PHP

```
// Define o limitador de cache
session_cache_limiter('must-revalidate');

// Inicia a sessão
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+7200);
```

No php.ini

```
    [session]
    session.save_handler = files ; sqlite (5.3) / user / memcache(d)
    session.serialize_handler = php ; php_serialize / wddx / php_binary / igbinary
    session.use_cookies = 1
    session.use_only_cookies = 1
    session.name = TESTE
    session.auto_start = 0
    session.cookie_lifetime = 0
    session.cookie_path = /
    session.cookie_domain =
    session.cookie_httponly =
    session.serialize_handler = php
    session.gc_probability = 1
    session.gc_divisor = 1000
    session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
    session.bug_compat_42 = Off
    session.bug_compat_warn = Off
    session.referer_check =
    session.entropy_length = 0
    session.cache_limiter = nocache
    session.cache_expire = 7200
    session.use_trans_sid = 0
    session.use_strict_mode = Off
    session.hash_function = 0
    session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
    url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
    session.upload_progress.cleanup = On
    session.upload_progress.enabled = On
    session.upload_progress.freq = "1%"
    session.upload_progress.min_freq = 1
    session.upload_progress.name = PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
    session.upload_progress.prefix = "upload_progress_"
```

Bom quando efetuo o login e vou no console do browser aparece a seção 'TESTE', e la mostra que ela vai expirar em 2 horas. Sempre que eu atualiza a página a data de expiração e atualizada.

O problema e que se eu deixar o sistema parado por uns 30 minutos e atualizar a página ele fala que a seção expirou.

Como resolvi isso?

Comment: Eu apostava em cookie... Menos dor de cabeça

Comment: seção e mais segura, pois os dados ficam no servidor.

Comment: Que dados? Não estás a guardar passwords etc... em sessão pois não?

Comment: sim armazeno o passwords na sessão

Comment: Não devias... Basta armazenares `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = True;` e pronto já sabes que o utilizador está login, com verificação `if($_SESSION['loggedin']) { ... está logado... } else { ...não está... }`

Comment: nao e bem assim que eu faço, tenho uma função que montem que pega o usuário e a senha em md5 que esta na seção e consulta no BD.

Comment: Hugo, não devias fazer isso, quanto muito guardas o id do user que está login, tipo: `$_SESSION['loggedin']['id'] = 3; $_SESSION['loggedin']['username'] = 'HuBor';` , tendo isto já podes acesso a tudo respeitante ao utilizador, com o id guardado em sessão vais buscando o que te interessa à BD sempre que quiseres sem que informação sensível ande de um lado para o outro (lado cliente <-> lado servidor). E há melhores metodos de hash do que md5, esse já é obsoleto para hash de passwords

Comment: ok, então como faço o sistema de login seguro? poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Há muita coisa na internet sobre isso... Se tiver tempo recomendo, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc&index=1 , antigo, mas é muito bom e abragente. Nesse caso ele só guarda o id do utilizador em sessão

Comment: @HugoBorges Precisa arrumar isso aqui, tá com 24 minutos só: `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440`

Comment: @Bacco vou colocar igual o 'cache_expire = 7200'

Comment: @HugoBorges ponha sempre um pouco maior que o tempo real

Comment: blz, mas sempre tenho que deixar ele igual ao 'cache_expire'?

Comment: Complementei minha resposta anterior para sua pergunta. Para duas horas, eu deixaria por exemplo 7800 (7200 + 10 minutinhos de folga)